# Colors sequences ignored during python test

Tags: python, colors, terminal, pytest

**related:** [timofurrer/colorful#23](https://github.com/timofurrer/colorful/issues/23)

---

I'm re-implementing [pure prompt in python](https://github.com/edouard-lopez/pure) so it can support more shell.

However, when testing color I got "unexecpected" behavior, *i.e.* one that I don't understand.

#### tests output

```
    def test_prompt_symbol_is_colored_for_successful_command():
        assert str(prompt.prompt_symbol()) == str(colors.primary('❯'))
>       assert str(prompt.prompt_symbol()) == '\x1b[38;2;155;48;255m❯\x1b[39m'
E       AssertionError: assert '❯' == '\x1b[38;2;155;48;255m❯\x1b[39m'
E         - ❯
E         + ❯   ← this one is purple
```

#### _colors_test.py_

```py
def test_prompt_symbol_is_colored_for_successful_command():
    assert str(prompt.prompt_symbol()) == str(colors.primary('❯'))
    assert str(prompt.prompt_symbol()) == '\x1b[38;2;155;48;255m❯\x1b[39m'
```

I run test with:

```
pytest -v tests/
```

#### *colors.py*

```py
import colorful

primary = colorful.purple1
mute = colorful.gray
```

#### *prompt.py*

```py
from pure import colors

def prompt_symbol(last_command_status=0):
    symbol = colors.primary('❯') if last_command_status == 0 else colors.danger('❯')
    return symbol
```

#### Question

The first assertion succeed, while the second failed despite the fact they **should be equivalent**. When I negate the first assertion the escape sequence are not present:

```py
>       assert str(prompt.prompt_symbol()) != str(colors.primary('❯'))
E       AssertionError: assert '❯' != '❯'
E        +  where '❯' = str(<colorful.core.ColorfulString object at 0x7f545276f080>)
E        +    where <colorful.core.ColorfulString object at 0x7f545276f080> = <function prompt_symbol at 0x7f54527b79d8>()
E        +      where <function prompt_symbol at 0x7f54527b79d8> = prompt.prompt_symbol
E        +  and   '❯' = str(<colorful.core.ColorfulString object at 0x7f545276f0b8>)
E        +    where <colorful.core.ColorfulString object at 0x7f545276f0b8> = <colorful.core.Colorful.ColorfulStyle object at 0x7f54527c2278>('❯')
E        +      where <colorful.core.Colorful.ColorfulStyle object at 0x7f54527c2278> = colors.primary
```

Manually executing command in python REPL gives me:

```py
>>> from pure import colors, prompt 
>>> str(colors.primary('❯'))
'\x1b[38;2;155;48;255m❯\x1b[39m'
>>> str(prompt.prompt_symbol())
'\x1b[38;2;155;48;255m❯\x1b[39m'
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with [`--capture=no` (or `-s`) flag from `pytest`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html?highlight=--capture%3Dno#setting-capturing-methods-or-disabling-capturing):

```
pytest -v --capture=no tests/
```

For details see https://github.com/timofurrer/colorful/issues/23#issuecomment-468008070.